# Инициализация таблицы дисков Linux LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, fdisk

Добрый день. Как инициализировать таблицу дисков как Linux LVM с помощью fdisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить тип раздела можно с помощью команды `t`, "Linux LVM" соответствует тип раздела `8e`. Примерный ход диалога:

```
Команда (m для справки): t
Номер раздела (1-3,5-10, default 10): 1
Шестнадцатеричный код (введите L для получения списка кодов): 8e
```

Сам физический том на разделе нужно создавать отдельно с помощью `pvcreate`.